# Why can’t I convert this tail recursive function into an iterative one in Rust?

Tags: rust, singly-linked-list, lifetime

I’m writing a function that removes the last node from a singly linked list:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Box<Self>>,
}
```

Here is my recursive version:

```rust
fn remove_last_node_recursive<T>(node_ref: &mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>) {
    let next_ref = &mut node_ref.as_mut().unwrap().next;

    if next_ref.is_some() {
        remove_last_node_recursive(next_ref);
    } else {
        *node_ref = None;
    }
}
```

The recursive version works fine, but I want to write an iterative version like the following one:

```rust
fn remove_last_node_iterative<T>(mut node_ref: &mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>) {
    loop {
        let next_ref = &mut node_ref.as_mut().unwrap().next;

        if next_ref.is_some() {
            node_ref = next_ref;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    *node_ref = None; // This line causes lifetime error.
}
```

I think my recursive version is tail recursive, so I should be able to convert it into an iterative one, but like the comment says, the commented code does not compile due to lifetime error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `*node_ref` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:28:5
   |
17 | fn remove_last_node_iterative<T>(mut node_ref: &mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>) {
   |                                                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
18 |     loop {
19 |         let next_ref = &mut node_ref.as_mut().unwrap().next;
   |                             -----------------
   |                             |
   |                             borrow of `*node_ref` occurs here
   |                             argument requires that `*node_ref` is borrowed for `'1`
...
28 |     *node_ref = None; // This line causes lifetime error.
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `*node_ref` occurs here
```

You can test the code in [the rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=27ed0dba175ce323cae8f9fe372dc5ed).

What did I do wrong, and what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the critical path of mutable references.

As the error message already mentions you mutably borrow the **node_ref** value and assign to **node_ref** variable, so it wanders into the function scope - same as your `None` assignment - because `break` could happen. You can check a next value without mutability and borrow as mutable in the inner scope of your condition, this way it works:

```
fn remove_last_node_iterative<T>(mut node_ref: &mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>) {
    while node_ref.as_ref().unwrap().next.is_some() {
        node_ref = &mut node_ref.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    }
    *node_ref = None;
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your explanation. What do you mean by “`break` could happen”? And your solution is not like my recursive one which only unwraps `node_ref` once in each iteration. Can you avoid unwrapping `node_ref` twice in each iteration?

Comment: The compiler behaves a bit stupid by considering your mutable borrow and both possibilities by your if condition. `next_ref` can be assigned for upper scope **and** loop break to keep using it (_unwinding_). Iirc rust 1.34 brought this pettiness. You cannot skip the second `.unwrap().next` because both are based on different mutability. @EFanZh

Comment: I found that `as_ref` is not necessary, `as_mut` can also work in your code. I think I should report an issue on this lifetime error behavior.